# Index is not being considered in mysql

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-optimization

I have a problem in deciding on index. I have a table in mySQL say X with atlas 70 million records. I need to query few fields based on filter like Year = X and Quarter = X and ( user = X or manager = X or ..)

I have an index on year and quarter which is not considered. So if it is considered, then less than 10% of the data is used.

I have index on year, quarter and all the user fields. Even then the index is not considered.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hard to say without knowing the query, the explain plan, the structure of the table and the other indexes + maybe a sample of the data. It could be that another index is more performant is this case, or that the cardinality is too low.

Comment: When I try to read the explain, it has possible_keys listed but "key" is just null. It says "Using where" in the extra field.

Comment: I am just saying select * from table_x where year = X and quarter = X

Comment: You need to edit your question and be way more specific than that. Otherwise it is simply not possible to answer.

Comment: You mentioned in your post above a more extensive condition involving `OR` expressions, which may be logically incompatible with using an index. Then in comments you describe simpler conditions. Which is it?

Comment: When asking for help with query optimization, you need to post the full SQL query you use, and the `SHOW CREATE TABLE <tablename>` output, and the `EXPLAIN` output. Please help us help you, and don't make us guess at these details!